# How do I programmatically show a keyboard for textbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have one textbox on a windows phone page and I want to show keyboard as soon as the page is loaded.

Is there any way to make this textbox already focused when I navigate to this page?

I considered using `Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput()` but I don't think it's a good solution in silverlight.

Comment: Would giving the focus after the page is loaded to your text-box automatically show up the keyboard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, I wouldn't manually show the keyboard. It may be an annoyance for those that have devices with a physical keyboard. In the load event for the page you could just call the Focus method on the textbox that you want to be selected. The Keyboard should automatically show as necessary.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            txtLongitude.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Override the [`OnNavigatedTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#Y0) method for the page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

  // Set focus to the TextBox, this will pop up the 
  // virtual keyboard
  myTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `textBox.Focus()` via a `Dispatcher` if you use it on the `OnNavigatedTo` event:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ShowKeyboard());
    }
}

private void ShowKeyboard()
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

The `if` statement here makes sure the keyboard is only shown when the page is not navigated to from the Back button.